# CNNs Scale/Rotation Invariance

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, scale-invariance, rotation

CNNs are translation-invariant due to the pooling layer. How can we make them scale/rotation invariant? I have beginner-level knowledge of Deep Learning so please help me understand.

Comment: Please expand your question and provide some example dataset.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This is a theoretical question: what do we do with a CNN to make it scale invariant and what do we do to make it rotation invariant?

Comment: I believe the same questions are already asked here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239076/about-cnn-kernels-and-scale-rotation-invariance